# Question marks instead of russian chars when getting data from Microsoft Azure Transact SQL using PDO with dblib driver

Tags: php, sql-server, azure, pdo

I'm trying to connect Microsoft Azure SQL Server from PHP. 
Currently PHP 5.5.9 on Ubuntu 14.04

Everything worked good until I upgraded the server to 16.04 and PHP 7.
Since that update preceeding unicode strings with 'N' characters stopped working. As I removed 'N's from prepared statements it started to function normally instead of one thing: When i insert or update with russian symbols they are stored as chineese.

I tried a lot of different things tomorrow trying to resolve this problem. Finally i decided to rollback to Ubuntu 14.04.
But to my surprise i got the same effect.

Here is my connection string:

```
$connection = new PDO ("dblib:version=7.0;charset=UTF-8;host=".AZURE_SQL_HOST.":".AZURE_SQL_PORT.";dbname=".AZURE_SQL_DB, AZURE_SQL_USER, AZURE_SQL_PASS);
```

I don't know what info should I provide. Could someone please guide me?

Thanks in advance!

**Update:**
I don't know what exactly happened but somehow I started to receive question marks instead. Seems like the chineese char problem was only with php7.

Now I can't get rid of this question marks.

Comment: charset of your db field?

Comment: @Eugen , it's standard SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally sorted everything out:

1. Chineese symbols have happened only in PHP7. In php7 I couldn't make PDO prepare statement with 'N' chars in any way.
2. When I danced around php7 I switched to named set passing variables style. And that was the root of problem. It seems like named (:name) parameter doesn't work with 'N' and question mark (?) parameter is ok.

This is ok:

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_field=?");
$statement->execute(['SOME_UNICODE_CHARS']);
```

And this is not:

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_field=:field");
$statement->execute([':field' => 'SOME_UNICODE_CHARS']);
```

Hope this can save somebody some time...